# How can I deal with a massive delete from Django Admin?

Tags: python, django

I'm working with Django 2.2.10.

I have a model called `Site`, and a model called `Record`.
Each record is associated with a single site (Foreign Key).

After my app runs for a few days/weeks/months, each site can have thousands of records associated with it. I use the database efficiently, so this isn't normally a problem.

In Django Admin, when I try to delete a site however, Django Admin tries to figure out every single associated object that will also be deleted, and because my ForeignKey uses `on_delete=models.CASCADE`, which is what I want, it tries to generate a page that lists thousands, possibly millions of records that will be deleted. Sometimes this succeeds, but takes a few seconds. Sometimes the browser just gives up waiting.

How can I have Django Admin not list every single `record` it intends to delete? Maybe just say something like "x number of records will be deleted" instead.

Update: Should I be overriding Django admin's delete_confirmation.html? It looks like the culprit might be this line:

```
<ul>{{ deleted_objects|unordered_list }}</ul>
```

Or is there an option somewhere that can be enabled to automatically not list every single object to be deleted, perhaps if the object count is over X number of objects?

Update 2: Removing the above line from delete_confirmation.html didn't help. I think it's the view that generates the deleted_objects variable that is taking too long. Not quite sure how to override a Django Admin view

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your admin class, and than you can delete with this action without warning

```
  actions = ["silent_delete"]

  def silent_delete(self, request, queryset):
    queryset.delete()
```

If you want to hide default delete action, add this to your admin class

```
  def get_actions(self, request):
    actions = super().get_actions(request)
    if 'delete_selected' in actions:
      del actions['delete_selected']
    return actions
```

Comment: I guess that's one way to go. The regular delete functionality will still be broken though - this just adds another way to delete that will actually work.

Comment: @John well you can hide regular delete functionality, and leave only new one :)

Answer (score 2):

Since django 2.1 you can override [get_deleted_objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_deleted_objects) to limit the amount of deleted objects listed (it's either a list or a nested list). The timeout is probably due to the django app server timing out on the view's response.

You could limit the size of the returned list:

```py
class YourModelAdmin(django.admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_deleted_objects(self, objs, request):
        deleted = super().get_deleted_objects(objs, request)
        deleted_objs = deleted[0]
        return (self.__limit_nested(deleted_objs),) + deleted[1:]

    def __limit_nested(self, objs):
        limit = 10
        if isinstance(objs, list):
            return list(map(self.__limit_nested, objs))
        if len(objs) > limit:
            return objs[:limit] + ['...']
        return objs
```

But chances are the call to super takes too long as well, so you probably want to `return [], {}, set(), []` instead of calling super; though it doesn't tell you about missing permissions or protected relations then (but I saw no alternative other than copy pasting code from django github). You will want to [override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model) the [delete_confirmation.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/delete_confirmation.html) and the [delete_selected_confirmation.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/delete_selected_confirmation.html) template as well. You'll also want to make sure the admin has permission to delete any related objects that might get deleted by the cascading deletes.

In fact, the deletion itself may take too long. It's probably best defer the deletion (and permission checks if those are slow too) to a [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) task.