# Suppress warning about on_delete=CASCADE in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have some foreign keys to auth-User with `on_delete=CASCADE`.

If someone deletes a user, Django displays this warning.

[image: django-admin-delete]

Is there a way to avoid this warning?

It would be great if I could avoid it for every ForeignKey indiviually.

Comment: The answer here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/60287014/15116314, might resolve your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid it for every foreign key the easiest way would be to overwrite the default [django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/delete_confirmation.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/delete_confirmation.html) template by adding a custom `delete_confirmation.html` template in your own project structure, there is documentation on doing this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).